# How to reduce flush when using native queries in spring-data-japa?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am currently working on a project using spring 4.2 and hibernate 4.3.

By profiling, I found that repository methods with `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query(nativeQuery=true)` takes time. It is because `org.hibernate.pa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList()` calls `javax.persistence.EntityManager.flush()` internally, regardless what flush-mode you use. This `flush()` takes time if a lot of entity is in the persistence context.

I think it can be avoided by calling `org.hibernate.SQLQuery.addSynchronizedEntityClass()`, but I don't know the best way to call `addSynchronizedEntityClass()` using spring-data-jpa (or any other way to tell hibernate not to flush.)

What is the best practice to reduce flush?

Answer (score 0):

You can set [flush mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setFlushMode-javax.persistence.FlushModeType-) to `COMMIT` for the desired (or all) sessions. Just keep in mind to manually flush the session if a query depends on the dirty session state.

Comment: Flush mode only affects to DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(). DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(), which is called when you call EntityManager.flush(), is not affected. It actually flushes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: was searching for this problem and found this question. if someone else stumbles here: with a native query you have to make sure that you don't have any transient state when you call it because it will only look db situation; so either let hibernate flush or, if the query is independent to your current state,put it outside of the transaction

Answer (score 0):

For a project I am working on, we are migrating from Hibernate EJB EM 3.6 to Hibernate JPA EM 4.3.8 and ran into this very situation.  I found a hibernate bug that talks about adding this flush to the native query ([HHH-8487](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8487)). It at least explained where the flush came from, but it seems that it recommends you tell the native query what entities to "synchronize" on.

```
Query jpaSqlQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery( ... );
jpaSqlQuery.unwrap( org.hibernate.SQLQuery.class )
           .addSynchronizedEntityClass( Person.class );
```

Prior to this, I think our app was sprinkling calls to flush before queries we knew would be affected by changes that we have made in a particular thread of code. In many cases, we don't have any. But the code above I think at least makes the query aware of what entities may be involved. You can even add more than one entity class to be part of this synchronization.

It's a solution, but may be time costly for migrating existing apps and could make it difficult to produce a general solution.